# How to create Swift variable with JSON literal string?

Tags: swift

I want to create a string variable with a JSON string. Swift doesn't seem to allow me to do this, where I use ` or ' to wrap the JSON string to escape it.

```
    var json = '{"variable":"hello world"}'
    var json = `{"variable":"hello world"}`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Swift `String` literals are **always** enclosed in double quotes `"` — see [here in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID286). There is no alternative syntax for string literals (like there is in Ruby for example)… at least as of Swift 1.2.

So if you need to put quotes in your string literal, you then need to escape them.

```
let json = "{\"variable\":\"hello world\"}"
```

*(the only other alternative if you have a lot of quotes to escape would be to load the JSON string from a resource file for example. But then that's not a String literal anymore)*

Comment: I'm aware of that but is there a better way besides escaping all the quotes in my json string?

Comment: No there isn't, that's why I said "String literals **are always** enclosed in double quotes". See [here in the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID286)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiline string to include json literal. This works even better when you have a common multi attribute json.

```
var json = """
{
  "variable": "hello world"
}
"""
```

From swift site:

> Because multiline string literals use three double quotation marks
> instead of just one, you can include a double quotation mark (")
> inside of a multiline string literal without escaping it.